# Empty pixels render black instead of just being invisible

Tags: rendering, texturing

so im trying to do some 3d rendering with my MC character, i've only used blender a few times over the past few years and i recently decided to try and learn how it works, well so far i've been figering things out and i know some basic stuff, now here is my issue, minecraft characters have an overlay and im trying to render with that overlay but whenever i try to render it, all parts of my texture that DONT have any pixels render as black

i changed the render engine to workbench and put the color to texture wich fixed it

[image: when viewed in the "Layout" tab]

[image: when rendered]

Comment: Under material properties, scroll down until you see "Blend Mode" and make sure it is not set to "opaque" (default).

Comment: Change world brightness